# ORD and CHR a file in Bash

Tags: bash, chr, ord

I build `ord` and `chr` functions and they work just fine.
But if I take a file that contains `\n`, for example:

```
hello
CHECK THIS HIT
YES
```

when I `ord` everything I don't get any new line values. Why is that? I'm writing in Bash.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
function ord { 
    ordr="`printf "%d\n" \'$1`" 
}

TEXT="`cat $1`"
for (( i=0; i<${#TEXT}; i++ )) 
do 
    ord "${TEXT:$i:1}" 
    echo "$ordr" 
done
```

Comment: Show your `ord` and `chr` functions, and how you use them with your file!

Comment: @lurker 
So I find out that the problem it's in how I store the file content I do
STR=`cat file1`
The newline values is absorbed like you said..
How can I store in a var file content

Comment: You're wrong: `STR=$(cat file1)` _doesn't “absorb” (whatever that means) newline values_. You're probably missing quotes, which is a, sadly, too common mistake. Show your code!

Comment: Look on this code:
STR=$(cat file1)
echo $STR
hello CHECK THIS HIT YES
It's all in one line.

Comment: That's because you're doing `echo $STR`, not `echo "$STR"`.

Comment: Amazing, Thanks a lot !
Can you explain me why the quotes make the difference ?

Comment: @lurker with `STR=$(cat file1)`, the newline characters _are not_ translated into spaces. Please learn how to check the content of a variable: either with `declare -p STR` or `printf '%q\n' "$STR"`, or, for a quick overview `echo "$STR"` _with quotes_. The only character that will get _absorbed_ is the null byte, as a Bash variable can't hold the null byte.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I had done, `echo $STR | od -cx` and saw spaces instead of newlines. Without the quotes. It was just illustrating that using `echo` without the quotes translated to spaces.

Comment: @JhonaBona99 see for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470652/linux-bash-redirect-a-string-to-a-file/25470688#25470688

Comment: Another question:
When I'm making for loop and ord ${TEXT:$i:1} I never catch the \n 
why is that?

Comment: did you read the answer? `ord "${TEXT:$i:1}"`

Comment: @lurker: without the quotes, you also have pathname expansion! `STR='*'; echo $STR`. Always quotes your variables unless you want nasty things to happen `:D`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf yes, I understand that. I deleted my comment to avoid confusion for the OP, but I was just illustrating that, without the quotes, there are issues.

Comment: @TomFenech It's not work with the quote either..

Comment: @JhonaBona99 just to reiterate: unless you show your code, it's hard to determine what you're doing wrong. But `${TEXT:$i:1}` should give you the new line if the index of the newline is indeed at `$i`.

Comment: @JhonaBona99 that's very likely because your `ord` command is badly written and misses lots of quotes all over the place! ***Please show your code***.

Comment: Your question was posted 41 minutes ago. 38 minutes ago I asked you to show your code. We have wasted so much time because you don't want to cooperate! Your question has 4 votes to close and 3 downvotes. Don't you understand that the only thing we're asking you to help you is that you show your code??? Edit your post and include your `ord` function and the way you use it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code at last, although I dispute the claim that it works just fine. There are a number of errors in that code, including some which I suspect means that it fails to run at all. I suggest that you go to http://www.shellcheck.net/ and deal with them, then [edit] your question.

Comment: @TomFenech I guess that the missing backticks were artifacts of the text format in the comment. I fixed that `:D`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `ord` function is really weird. Maybe it would be better to write it as:

```
function ord { 
    printf -v ordr "%d" "'$1"
}
```

Then you would use it as:

```
TEXT=$(cat "$1")
for (( i=0; i<${#TEXT}; i++ )); do 
    ord "${TEXT:$i:1}" 
    printf '%s\n' "$ordr"
done
```

This still leaves two problems: you won't be able to have null bytes and you won't see trailing newlines. For example (I called your script `banana` and `chmod +x banana`):

```
$ ./banana <(printf 'a\0b\n')
97
98
```

Two problems show here: the null byte is removed from Bash in the `TEXT=$(cat "$1")` part, as a Bash variable can't contain null bytes. Moreover, this step also trims trailing newlines.

A more robust approach would be to use `read`:

```
while IFS= read -r -n 1 -d '' char; do
    ord "$char"
    printf '%s\n' "$ordr"
done < "$1"
```

With this modification:

```
$ ./banana <(printf 'a\0b\n')
97
0
98
10
```

Note that this script will depend on your locale. With my locale (`LANG="en_US.UTF-8`):

```
$ ./banana <(printf 'a\0ℂ\n')
97
0
8450
10
```

whereas:

```
$ LANG= ./banana <(printf 'a\0ℂ\n')
97
0
226
132
130
10
```

That's to show you that Bash doesn't read *bytes*, but *characters*. So depending on how you want Bash to treat your data, set `LANG` accordingly.

---

If your script only does that, it's much simpler to not use an `ord` function at all:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -n 1 -d '' char; do
    printf '%d\n' "'$char"
done < "$1"
```

It's that simple!