# Duplicate numbers using $RANDOM in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, random, debian

I wrote a script with bash in while loop. The code:

```
number=0
while [ 1500 -gt $number ]
do
  var="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz"
  letter1="${var:$(( RANDOM % ${#var} )):1}"
  letter2="${var:$(( RANDOM % ${#var} )):1}"
  a=$RANDOM
  b=$RANDOM
  c=$(( $a * $b))
  echo "$letter1$letter2 $c" >> a.txt
  number=$(( 1 + $number ))
done
```

but now I see duplicate numbers in result:

```
Result:
ab 15474
at 15474
yh 15474
gd 15474
re 18696
jg 18696
```

The numbers are duplicate.

I guess the `$RANDOM` changes after a invariant time and my script starts again the the `while` loop faster than the `$RANDOM` changes.

Can you help me an other randomization way?

Comment: Not the most efficient, but you could read from `/dev/urandom` and filter for only-letters

Comment: Was RANDOM changed in any way before this code is executed? `man bash` warns that while RANDOM should produce a new random number each time it is referenced, it will lose this special property if it is unset at some point. Also, I [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/l0AKzs)

Comment: @knittl how can i use the /dev/urandom . im not pro at linux. i use debian

Comment: all guys. i want to save the random result to a $reslut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your script and it worked fine for me.

There are many ways to [generate random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/how-to-generate-random-number-in-bash) in bash. One is using the `/dev/random` special device file. The `/dev/random` uses the noise collected from the device drivers and other sources to generate random data. The od (octal dump) command can extract a number of bytes and displays their decimal equivalent.

```
od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom
```

Here, `-t d` specifies that the output format should be signed decimal; `-N 1` says to read one byte from /dev/urandom.

One other way is using the `jot` command:

```
jot -r 10 1 1000
```

Here we generate 10 numbers between 1 and 1000. `-r` specifies to generate random number.

Comment: how to install jot . i didnt see that in comand list and apt install list

Comment: Try this  `sudo apt-get install athena-jot `

Comment: how to save this random result to a Variable(i used google translate for the Variable )(the $ in bash)

Comment: @Aliemaditaj  you can use command substitution (using `resultVariable=$(command)` ) to write the result to the variable. For example, `a=$(jot -r 2 1 1000)` or  `a=$(od -A n -t d -N 1 /dev/urandom)`  will store the results in `a` and then `echo $a` will print the result.

Comment: it dont works at high numbers . please see this screenshot: https://ibb.co/5LDzBbq

Comment: Pictures of text are pretty universally loathed. Maybe at this point create a new question with your *actual* requirements instead of heaping on follow-up questions in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tr` together with `/dev/urandom`:

```
tr -dc 'a-z' </dev/urandom | head -c 2; echo
```

Set the number of characters you want with the `-c` option of the `head` function.

To generate random digit, use another set in the `tr` command:

```
tr -dc '0-9' </dev/urandom | head -c 4; echo
```

Comment: @tripleee I don't get your point. Do you mean that the output isn't random? or that there isn't digit?

Comment: That there are no digits. You have solved the first half of the question but not the second.

Comment: @tripleee ok, kind of misunderstood the question, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

@j23 has given a very reasonable operational answer.  By way of possible explanation of the behaviour you observed, the number you are printing is not a single `$RANDOM` value, but the product of two such values.  Pairs of consecutive outputs of a pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) are not necessarily as independent as you might like.  E.g., Matlab `randn` had a correlation problem in 2006 (arXiv:math/0603058).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C
for((i=0; i<1500; ++i)); do
    IFS='' read -n 4 -d '' bytes
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476611/ord-and-chr-a-file-in-bash
    printf -v a %u "'${bytes:2:1}"
    a=$((a%255))
    printf -v b %u "'${bytes:3:1}"
    b=$((b%255))
    printf "%s %s\n" "$(
        tr '\000-\011\013-\140\173-\377' 'a-za-za-za-za-za-za-za-za-z' <<<"${bytes:0:2}"
    )" $((${a#-}*${b#-}))
done</dev/urandom
```

The `%u` conversion oddly creates really big numbers when the character code is above 0x80, and the modulo 255 of that creates a negative number, so I had to do some nonobvious workarounds to fix that. Perhaps you could come up with a less contorted way to unpack two bytes into an unsigned 15-bit number.

Here's an update which gets results in the range 200000-1000000 in the second column. It needs two additional random bytes and then performs a modulo and addition on the result to bring it into the correct range. This is outside the reach of the Bash built-in arithmetic so I used `bc` instead.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export LC_ALL=C
for((i=0; i<1500; ++i)); do
    IFS='' read -n 6 -d '' bytes
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476611/ord-and-chr-a-file-in-bash
    printf -v a %u "'${bytes:2:1}"
    a=$((a%255))
    printf -v b %u "'${bytes:3:1}"
    b=$((b%255))
    printf -v c %u "'${bytes:4:1}"
    c=$((c%255))
    printf -v d %u "'${bytes:5:1}"
    d=$((d%255))
    printf "%s %s\n" "$(
        tr '\000-\011\013-\140\173-\377' 'a-za-za-za-za-za-za-za-za-z' <<<"${bytes:0:2}"
    )" $(bc <<<"((${a#-}*${b#-}*${c#-}*${d#-})%800000)+200000")
done</dev/urandom
```

This is getting pretty complex, though. If Bash is not essential for you, try this Python 3 script.

```py
from random import choice, randrange
from string import ascii_lowercase

for r in range(1500):
  print('{0}{1} {2}'.format(
    choice(ascii_lowercase),
    choice(ascii_lowercase),
    200000+randrange(999999800000)))
```

Comment: I guess you want bigger numbers than 15-bit actually, but your examples all look like they are less than 32768. What is the expected range actually?

Comment: i need numbers beetwen 200 000 and 1 000 000 000 000

Comment: and save them on a $

Comment: What does "save them on a $" mean?

Comment: Just use `printf -v variable` in the last statement in the loop as well.